# How do I implement interrupt in micro framework?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

I can't compile code for `stm32f4discovery` in .NET with VS2010.

Using `NETMF 4.2`

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using Microsoft.SPOT;
    using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;

    namespace MFConsoleApplication1
    {

        public class Program
        {
            private static InterruptPort interruptPort;

            public static void Main()
            {
                interruptPort =  new InterruptPort(Cpu.Pin.GPIO_Pin2,
                                               false,
                                               Port.ResistorMode.PullUp,
                                               rt.InterruptMode.InterruptEdgeLevelLow);

                interruptPort.OnInterrupt += new NativeEventHandler(port_OnInterrupt);


                 Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
            }


             private static void port_OnInterrupt(uint port, uint state, TimeSpan time)
             {
                Debug.Print("Pin=" + port + " State=" + state + " Time=" + time);
                interruptPort.ClearInterrupt();
             }
         }
    }
```

On compilation, I receive the following error: 
`No overload for 'port_OnInterrupt' matches delegate 'Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.NativeEventHandler'`

How  I can compile the code?

I've took this example from book "Expert .NET Micro framework".

Comment: From the documentation it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 6):

Even though the documentation states that the last argument is a `TimeSpan` I think it really is a `DateTime` in the .net microframeworks I have been using.

So instead of

```
 private static void port_OnInterrupt(uint port, uint state, TimeSpan time)
```

try

```
 private static void port_OnInterrupt(uint port, uint state, DateTime time)
```

And another hint: instead of

```
 interruptPort.OnInterrupt += new NativeEventHandler(port_OnInterrupt);
```

you can write

```
 interruptPort.OnInterrupt += port_OnInterrupt;
```

which is equivalent but more readable.

Comment: Timespan did seem an odd choice of argument.